# PayPal Automatically authorise incoming payments of a different currency

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I am using the PayPal API Express Checkout to process payments for places at our various events. Our PayPal account is in GBP and if we are charging our customers in GBP everything works perfectly.

If we charge our customers in USD the payment response comes back as "Pending" until we log in to PayPal and authorise the payment because of the charge associated with converting from USD to GBP.

Is there a way of automating this? So that it works the same as GBP?

We have thousands of people registering for some of these events so as you can imagine our Accounts Dept do not want to manually authorise all of these payments and then tick the delegates off as paid.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been going through all of the PayPal settings with a fine tooth comb since I put this up.

Under Account Settings, click on Payment Receiving Preferences.

Under there one of the options is to "Allow payments sent to me in a currency I do not hold." I changed this setting to Yes accept and it now works fine.

Hope this might help others.

Paul